# How can I send document with custom name in telegram bot using node Js?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Currenly I am working on telegram bot project in which I want to send the custom filename of my choice, then what should i do ?

In Simple words,
I am getting file from api as "index.pdf", But I want to send file to my user with my custom name "myfilename.pdf".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [sendDocument](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument) method from the Telegram API you can send local document with a custom filename like this (note that [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) npm package must be installed, and [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) can be replaced with any HTTP library):

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');

...

const url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}/sendDocument`;

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('chat_id', chatID);
formData.append('document', fs.createReadStream('./index.pdf'), 'myfilename.pdf');

await axios.post(url, formData, {
    headers: formData.getHeaders(),
})
```